# SQL Server - How to list logins assigned to a credential?

Tags: sql-server, authentication, credentials

A SQL Server credential is used to allow SQL Server User (not Windows User) to have an identity outside of the SQL Server and to enable them performing various tasks.

From the http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189828.aspx site, credential can be added to a (SQL Server) Login as follows:

```
ALTER LOGIN Mary5
ADD CREDENTIAL EKMProvider1;
GO
```

My question is, where can I see in the system tables/views the Logins/Users that have been assigned to a given credential? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In my case I needed to see how and where Credentials were being used, and that covers not just logins but also proxies as well. I found these two queries together gave me a useful overview:

```
SELECT c.credential_id, c.name AS Credential_Name, c.credential_identity, p.name AS Proxy_Name, p.enabled, p.description
FROM master.sys.credentials c
LEFT JOIN msdb..sysproxies p
ON  c.credential_id = p.credential_id

SELECT c.credential_id, c.name AS Credential_Name, c.credential_identity, p.name AS Principal_Name, p.type_desc, p.is_disabled, p.default_database_name
FROM master.sys.credentials c
LEFT JOIN master.sys.server_principals p
ON  c.credential_id = p.credential_id
```

Tested on SQL 2008 R2 through 2016.

Answer (score 1):

I think something similar to this should work for you.

```
SELECT sp.name
FROM sys.server_principals AS sp INNER JOIN sys.credentials AS c 
  ON sp.credential_id = c.credential_id
WHERE c.name = 'YOUR_CREDENTIAL_NAME';
```

Here is more information on the sys.credentials and sys.server_principals catalog views:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188754.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189745.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Having searched for the answer to the same question and found a useful method which contains mapping between logins and credentials.

Here is my solution:

```
SELECT c.name FROM sys.server_principal_credentials pc
INNER JOIN sys.credentials c
    ON pc.credential_id = c.credential_id
WHERE principal_id IN 
(
    SELECT principal_id FROM sys.server_principals 
    WHERE name = ORIGINAL_LOGIN()
)
```

@@VERSION = SQL Server 2008 R2